# Gridview getting value of a BoundField set to Visible=False

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can i get the value of a field that is set to Visible=false? as follows:

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="Line Item ID" Visible="false"/>
```

but when i try to get it with

```
 int temID = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[0].Text);
```

It cant find it and throws an exception, but if I make it Visible="true" it works.

How can I retrieve the value if visible = false?

Comment: is ItemID the primary key in your data set?

Comment: At what point do you want the value of ItemID?  While DataBinding or on a Row Event?

Comment: I am currently coding it on GridView_DataBound

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the definition of your GridView, add

```
<asp:GridView .... DataKeyNames="ItemID" ...>
```

You also need to use OnRowDataBound, not OnDataBound

```
<asp:GridView .... DataKeyNames="ItemID" ... OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound">
```

Then in your code behind, something like this

```
protected void GridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
          int ItemId = Int32.Parse(YourGridView.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Values[0].ToString());
     }
}
```

I did not test this code before posting.  But this is the general idea of what you need to do.  It may or may not work as is.

Comment: OnDataBound is an event for the entire GridView - you want a specific row's information, get it when the row is being databound.

Comment: The only thing is that its comming with a int.Parse(string) has some invalid arguments

Comment: Then use TryParse?  Not sure how your DataKey would cause such a message - it should never be null or empty since it is the Primary Key.

Comment: It is not complaining about its contents but the format of the statement after the equal sign

Comment: I mentioned I hadn't tested the code.  Have you tried to get it working?

Comment: I edited my answer - still haven't been able to test, but perhaps this approach is better.

Comment: I was already using DataKeyNames for another column but found I could use multiple DataKeyNames.  Syntax is:  DataKeyNames="ServerId, isOnline" .
Using this worked perfectly.

Answer (score 11):

Another way without all those code is something like that:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .Hide
    {
        display: none;
    }
</style>
```

in the page or in your css file.
And set this class to your boundField:

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="Id" ItemStyle-CssClass="Hide" HeaderStyle-CssClass="Hide" />
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 1):

I wrestled with this for a bit, but ended up (instead of adding RowDataBound events), simply getting the values out of the DataKeys when I needed them, eg (in VB):

```
x = MyGrid.DataKeys(oRow.RowIndex).Values(0).ToString)
```

Obviously this is suitable for when the values *are* data keys... when not it's probably not a good idea.

Answer (score -1):

If you have `IsVisible=false` the control is not rendered at all to the client and hence you won't be able to get the value back on postback. You can use style `display:none` to not display it on the client, but still being rendered.

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="ItemID" HeaderText="Line Item ID" style="display:none;"/>
```

In this case you'll be able to get the value back.

An alternative to this would be to use `<input type="hidden" runat="server">` control.

Comment: 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField' does not have a public property named 'style'.

Comment: if you put it in aspx page it would get rendered in the final html control. If you want to do it from server side you can do it via `YourBoundField.Attributes["style"] = "display:none"`. Also `System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField` does have a `ControlStyle` property, though I don't think it would have a `display` property.

Answer (score -3):

try adding the attribute

```
runat="Server"
```