# Concise way to format columns in a gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I realize this is an easy question, but despite searching I can't find anything specific towards my problem.

I have a gridview populated with 9 or so columns. I want to both change the column names and edit the number of visible columns. So instead of

```
| x | y | z |
  2   6   7
```

I'd like

```
|new x|new z|
   2     7
```

I realize that I can manually edit the column names and set them to visible or not, but is there a way to do something like: if (column = y) then (display column) and (column name = new y)?

Much appreciated.

Comment: You can do that from your codebehind

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6945572/gridview-getting-value-of-a-boundfield-set-to-visible-false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can handle the [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) event to modify the columns when they are bound and apply any changes you want at that point.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this inside the page load event, or grid load:

```
foreach(BoundField b in grid.Columns)
{
   if(b.HeaderText == 'y')
   {
      b.HeaderText = "new y";
   } else {
      b.Visible = false;
   }
}
```